# Eselsbrücken für Funktionsverbgefüge

Tags: verb-usage

Ich gebe mir viel Mühe, um Funktionsverbgefüge (FVG) richtig zu verwenden.  Meistens verwechsle ich das Verb mit etwas ähnliches wie folgende:

- etw. in Erwägung ziehen (mit *nehmen* verwechselt)
- aus etw. Vorteil zu ziehen (mit *nehmen* verwechselt)
- etw. in Besitz nehmen (mit *ziehen* verwechselt)
- auf etw. Einfluss nehmen (mit *ziehen* verwechselt)
- etw. in Dienst stellen (mit *bringen* oder *setzen* verwechselt)
- etw. in Betrieb nehmen (mit *bringen* oder *setzen* verwechselt)
- etw. in Kraft setzen (mit *bringen* verwechselt)
- etw. in Ordnung bringen (mit *setzen* verwechselt)

Ich benutzte Anki, um diese FVG zu üben.  Ich habe schon viele Karten mit Beispiele und Sätze erstellt, aber ich begehe immer die gleichen Fehler.  Obwohl ich gut verstehe, dass das Verb in FVG kleinen Wert besitzt, es ist für mich noch wichtig die korrekte Anwendung zu üben.

Kann jemand mir Eselsbrücken o. A. bieten, um die richtigen Verben zu lernen?  Sogar ein paar Erklärungen, z.B., warum klingt *etw. in Erwägung zu nehmen* oder *etw. in Ordnung setzen* falsch?  (Wird vielleicht andere Bedeutung vermittelt, u.s.w.?)

Comment: I believe these are called [light verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_verb) constructions in English, and are a feature of many languages. They are often the result of historical accident rather than logic. So I have no idea, for example, why you say "take a break" and "throw a party" rather than "throw a break" and "take a party". I assume the same holds in German.

Comment: Manche deiner "Verwechslungen" ergeben durchaus gängige Wendungen, wie z.B. "in Betrieb setzen" oder "in Dienst bringen".

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann nur zu einem Beispiel etwas beitragen:

*In Betrieb nehmen* ist der Begriff für die Kundenseite, ein Energiekonzern nimmt etwa ein Kraftwerk in Betrieb.

Es gibt aber auch *in Betrieb setzen*, das bezieht sich auf die Seite des Kraftwerk-Lieferanten und umfasst alles, was zuvor passieren muss, Installation, Verkabelung, Software-Installation, Anlagentest, etc.

Ich habe [hier](https://www.weka-manager-ce.de/maschinenrichtlinie/inbetriebsetzung-oder-inbetriebnahme-warum-sie-genau-hinschauen-sollten/) eine ausführliche Erklärung gefunden.

Generell sind deine *FVG*s etwas bürokratisch angehaucht, das Stichwort heißt *Nominalstil*.  *In Erwägung ziehen* wird gerne von Politikern verwendet, Normalsterblichen reicht oft *überlegen*, Ähnliches gilt für *auf etwas Einfluss nehmen* und *beeinflussen*.